gradle build failing with premature end of content-length delimited message body
The gradle build I'm trying to do, contains a proprietary plugin, which is failing with a message
Premature end of Content-Length demlimited message body (expected 15,825,247; received: 1,560,064)

which i believe is server issue, but is there any way to avoid downloading the plugin by using local jar?
I can't add the jars as dependencies, I need to use it as plugin.

Your internet connection seems to be unstable, try using wifi or lan if you are using mobile data, or simply wait out a few hours if its not a time sensitive issue.

It is a company project, and I've to complete asap.

I'm sure you don't control your internet speed, simply report this issue to your project manager or team lead.
